# How to pass text input data to shortcode

Tags: shortcode

If I have a shortcode like
`[api_request q=12,45]`

How do I pass the data of the text input to the shortcode option `q`

We can use the `$_POST` but it seems like we need to do a post request to access `$_POST` hence how to do a post request in a text input in HTML and possibly reference the text input id by `$_POST['id_of_the_text_input']`to pass the data to the shortcode option `q` by `[api_request q=$_POST['id_of_the_text_input']]`?

Comment: You need to post your shortcode function for "api_request"

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this in the shortcode function for `[api_request]`.

Here's a potential answer with a ternary that would check if the `$_POST` value exists, if so, sanitize and use it, otherwise use the value passed in the shortcode:

```
$q = ( isset( $_POST['q'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['q'] ) ? $atts['q'];
```

This is simply a guess, since you didn't include the actual shortcode function in your question, which you would need to do in order to be able to give a practical answer.  I would amend this answer accordingly with additional info.